# Solve $\cot^2(x) -\cot(x) - 1=0$

Tags: trigonometry

Find all real solutions for the equation:

$$\cot^2(x) -\cot(x) - 1=0$$

Tried solving, but didn't get a special angle. Is it possible to get a special angle? Or does it need to be completely solved with a calculator, and if so.. How? Thank you.

Comment: is that equation equal to zero

Comment: Hint: let $u=\cot x$. It's a hidden quadratic, solvable by normal methods.

Comment: I set it equal to zero, so it can be solved. Rollback if you disagree.

Comment: Yes, its equal to 0 DeNiSkA

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

As $\cot x\ne0,$

multiply both sides by $\tan^2x,$

$$1-\tan x -\tan^2x=0\iff\tan x=1-\tan^2x\iff\tan2x=2$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\cot x =t$$
Then $$t^2-t-1=0$$

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you will be able to find a simple special angle.
Take a look at the diagram. One angle that you're looking for is the red one. Solving for the quadratic is the more fruitful path to follow.

[image]